# Android Iterating over nested Objects in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a Tournament object that contains a list of Match objects. I would like to display some tournament details and then list matches underneath also with some details. The problem is that it can be 1 Tournament to 3 Matches or 1-4, etc.

**Tournament 1**

  +Match 1

  +Match 2

**Tournament 2**

  +Match 1

  +Match 2

  +Match 3

I have been trying to use multiple views within `RecyclerView` and can get the 1-1 relationship working but I am uncertain where to add the iteration, I have been testing various thing with the `onBindViewHolder` to no avail, a little direction would be much appreciated.

```
public class MultiViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Tournament> mTournaments;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_Tournament  = 0;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_Match = 1;

    class TournamentHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ...
    }

    class MatchHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mTournaments.get(position).getType();
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_Tournament: return new TournamentHolder (...);
            case VIEW_TYPE_Match: return new MatchHolder (...);
            default: return new TournamentHolder(...);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_Tournament:
                TournamentHolder tournamentHolder = (TournamentHolder)holder;
                ..
                break;
            case VIEW_TYPE_Match:
                MatchHolder matchHolder = (MatchHolder)holder;
                ...
                break;
            default:
                ....
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out @Intdef and using it for your VIEW TYPES.  http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations

Comment: @petey Thanks, i'll look into using support annotations as typedefs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have worked around this problem by passing in a separate array that acts as a map, basically my adapter will look something like `adapter(map, tournament, matches)` and this allows me to display my views appropriately.

Feel free to let me know of a better way if you have one.

Comment: What does the map exactly do? I am trying to do almost the same with  a list of tournmanents and matches inside the tournament.